# Why does my code remove 999 in my replacement code?

Tags: python, for-loop, encode, str-replace, string-substitution

I have the code below to replace all punctuation with 999 and all alphabet characters with its number position. I have included the print statement that confirms punctuation is being replaced. However I seem to override with my remaining code to replace the other characters.

```
import string
def encode(text):
    punct = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
    for x in text.lower(): 
        if x in punct: 
            text = text.replace(x, ".999")
            print(text)
        nums = [str(ord(x) - 96) 
                for x in text.lower()
                    if x >= 'a' and x <= 'z'
                    ]
    return ".".join(nums)
print(encode(str(input("Enter Text: "))))
```

Input: `'Morning! \n'`

Output: `'13.15.18.14.9.14.7 \n'`

Expected Output: `13.15.18.14.9.14.7.999`

Comment: Could you give at least one actual example of your input, received output, and expected output?  I have no idea what problem I should be looking for here.

Comment: For Example Morning! should be (13.15.18.14.9.14.7.999)

Comment: Try to come up with a *separate* function that, given a **single character** of the input, tells you the **integer value** that it should represent. Then try to use that separate function to create the text you want, all at once.

Comment: As an aside: You *do not need* to `import string` to use string methods - but you should probably be using it for the *constant strings* it provides, such as `string.punctuation` which is equal to `'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'`. Also, `input` returns a string already; it accomplishes nothing to use `str` on the result.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have two independent logical "stories" here.  One replaces punctuation with `999`.  The other filters out all the letters and builds an independent list of their alphabetic positions.

```
    nums = [str(ord(x) - 96) 
            for x in text.lower()
                if x >= 'a' and x <= 'z'
                ]
return ".".join(nums)
```

Note that this does nothing to alter `text`, and it takes nothing but letters from `text`.  If you want to include the numbers, do so:

```
    nums = [str(ord(x) - 96) 
               if x >= 'a' and x <= 'z'
               else x
                  for x in text.lower()              
                ]
return ".".join(nums)
```

Output of `print(encode("[hello]"))`:

```
..9.9.9.8.5.12.12.15...9.9.9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    nums = [str(ord(x) - 96) 
            for x in text.lower()
                if x >= 'a' and x <= 'z'
                ]
```

This means: take every character from the lowercase version of the string, and **only if it is between `'a'` and `'z'`**, convert the value and put the result in `nums`.

In the first step, you replace a bunch of punctuation with text that includes `'.'` and `'9'` characters. But neither `'9'` nor `'.'` is between `'a'` and `'z'`, so of course neither is preserved in the second step.

---

Now that I understand what you are going for: you have fundamentally the wrong approach to splitting up the problem. You want to separate the two halves of the rule for "encoding" a given part of the input. But what you want to do is separate the *whole rule* for encoding a *single element*, from the *process of applying a single-element rule to the whole input*. After all - that is what list comprehensions *do*.

This is the concept of *separation of concerns*. The two business rules are part of the same concern - because implementing one rule *doesn't help you implement the other*. Being able to encode one input character, though, *does* help you encode the whole string, because there is a tool for that exact job.

We can have a complicated rule for single characters - no problem. Just put it in a separate function, so that we can give it a meaningful name and keep things simple to understand. Conceptually, our individual-character encoding is a *numeric* value, so we will consistently encode as a number, and then let the string-encoding process do the conversion.

```
def encode_char(c):
    if c in '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~''':
        return 999
    if 'a' <= c.lower() <= 'z':
        return ord(c) - 96
    # You should think about what to do in other cases!
    # In particular, you don't want digit symbols 1 through 9 to be
    # confused with letters A through I.
    # So I leave the rest up to you, depending on your requirements.
```

Now we can apply the overall encoding process: we want a string that puts `'.'` in between the string representations of the values. That's straightforward:

```
def encode(text):
    return '.'.join(str(encode_char(c)) for c in text)
```